# nltk's stopwords returns "TypeError: argument of type 'LazyCorpusLoader' is not iterable"

Tags: nlp, preprocessing, nltk, text

While trying to remove stopwords using the nltk package, the following error occurred:

```
from tqdm import tqdm 
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

preprocessed_reviews = []
for sentance in tqdm(final["Text"].values):
    sentance = ' '.join(e.lower() for e in sentance.split() if e.lower() not in stopwords)
```

> ```
> TypeError                                 
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-136-ac5c19fafd9c> in <module>()
> ---> 7     sentance = ' '.join(e.lower() for e in sentance.split() if e.lower() not in stopwords)
>      8     preprocessed_reviews.append(sentance.strip())
>      9 
>
> TypeError: argument of type 'LazyCorpusLoader' is not iterable
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of items that could be improved in your code:

- `nltk.corpus.stopwords` is a `nltk.corpus.util.LazyCorpusLoader`. You might want `stopwords.words('english')`, a list of stop English words.
- It can cause bugs to update a variable as you iterate through it, for example `sentance` in your code.
- In your code `preprocessed_reviews` is not being updated.
- You might want to tokenize instead of `str.split()`.

Here is a revision version:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from tqdm import tqdm

reviews_raw = ('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', "I have been doing what I should not been doing")
reviews_processed = []
for sentence in tqdm(reviews_raw):
    reviews_processed.append(' '.join(token.lower() for token in nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) if token.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')))

assert reviews_processed == ['quick brown fox jumps lazy dog', '']
```

Comment: Yes, The above improvements helped execute the code without issue. split() didnot cause any issue but tokenizing is a good concept here in this case. Thank you. !